# Clear "Zombie" Icons from System Tray using VB (attempt at translating from C++)

Tags: vb.net

There is no (apparent) API for managing icons in the system tray in Windows.  Applications that live in the system tray that are aborted through **Task Manager**, or end without a proper shutdown (error out) will leave their icons in the system tray.  Restarting the application then puts another icon in the tray.  The *zombie* icons persist and the only official way to remove them is to float your mouse over them and **POOF** - they disappear.  There simply is no Win32 API for clearing these out.  In my research I have found that a lot of folks are looking for the ability to clear these out. I even found one commercial product at [APPSVOID](https://www.appsvoid.com/products/systray-refresh/) But it seems rather expensive...
I *suspect* the commercial product uses hacks that can be found in various places in languages other than VB. One such can be found at [Refresh Notification Area](https://smklancher.github.io/oldprojects/project/id/88/Refresh_Notification_Area) This works, but is written entirely in C++.  I'm not a C++ Programmer so I spent some time clumsily refactoring the C++ to vb.net (Framework 4.8 in a Winforms application) and came up with the following and would love it if someone smarter than me could look over my shoulder, laugh a little, and help out:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class ClearSystemTray

    Private Const WM_MOUSEMOVE As UInteger = &H200

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function PostMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FindWindowW")>
    Public Shared Function FindWindowW(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpClassName As String, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function FindWindowEx(ByVal parentHandle As IntPtr, ByVal childAfter As IntPtr, ByVal lclassName As String, ByVal windowTitle As String) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Private Shared Function GetClientRect(ByVal hWnd As System.IntPtr, ByRef lpRECT As Rectangle) As Integer
    End Function

Public Shared Async Function ClearTray() As Task(Of Task)
        Dim SystemTrayContainerHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowW("Shell_TrayWnd", Nothing)
        Dim systemTrayHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(SystemTrayContainerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "TrayNotifyWnd", Nothing)
        Dim sysPagerHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(systemTrayHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "SysPager", Nothing)
        Dim NotificationAreaHandle = FindWindowEx(sysPagerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "Notification Area")

        If NotificationAreaHandle = IntPtr.Zero Then
            NotificationAreaHandle = FindWindowEx(sysPagerHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "User Promoted Notification Area")
            Dim notifyIconOverflowWindowHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowW("NotifyIconOverflowWindow", Nothing)
            Dim overflowNotificationAreaHandle As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(notifyIconOverflowWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "ToolbarWindow32", "Overflow Notification Area")
            Await RefreshTrayArea(NotificationAreaHandle)
            Await RefreshTrayArea(notifyIconOverflowWindowHandle)
            Await RefreshTrayArea(overflowNotificationAreaHandle)
        Else
            Await RefreshTrayArea(NotificationAreaHandle)
        End If

        Application.DoEvents()

        Return Task.CompletedTask

End Function

Private Shared Async Function RefreshTrayArea(windowHandle As IntPtr) As Task(Of Task)
        Dim rect As Rectangle
        GetClientRect(windowHandle, rect)
        Dim iPos As Integer
        Await Task.Run(Sub()
                           For x As Integer = 0 To rect.Right - 1 Step 5
                               For y As Integer = 0 To rect.Bottom - 1 Step 5
                                   iPos = (y << 16) + x
                                   PostMessage(windowHandle, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, iPos)
                               Next
                               Application.DoEvents()
                           Next
                       End Sub)

                           Return Task.CompletedTask

End Function
```

Since I can barely read the C++ code I am not really confident that I did this correctly - but... it appears to work.
Here is the original C++ code from the above mentioned site:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define FW(x,y) FindWindowEx(x, NULL, y, L"")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND hNotificationArea;
    RECT r;

    //WinXP
    GetClientRect(
        hNotificationArea = FindWindowEx(
            FW(FW(FW(NULL, L"Shell_TrayWnd"), L"TrayNotifyWnd"), L"SysPager"),
            NULL,
            L"ToolbarWindow32",
            L"Notification Area"),
        &r);
    
    for (LONG x = 0; x < r.right; x += 5)
        for (LONG y = 0; y < r.bottom; y += 5)
            SendMessage(
                hNotificationArea,
                WM_MOUSEMOVE,
                0,
                (y << 16) + x);
    

    //Visible icons
    GetClientRect(
        hNotificationArea = FindWindowEx(
            FW(FW(FW(NULL, L"Shell_TrayWnd"), L"TrayNotifyWnd"), L"SysPager"),
            NULL,
            L"ToolbarWindow32",
            L"User Promoted Notification Area"),
        &r);
    
    for (LONG x = 0; x < r.right; x += 5)
        for (LONG y = 0; y < r.bottom; y += 5)
            SendMessage(
                hNotificationArea,
                WM_MOUSEMOVE,
                0,
                (y << 16) + x);


    //Hidden icons
    GetClientRect(
        hNotificationArea = FindWindowEx(
            FW(NULL, L"NotifyIconOverflowWindow"),
            NULL,
            L"ToolbarWindow32",
            L"Overflow Notification Area"),
        &r);
    
    for (LONG x = 0; x < r.right; x += 5)
        for (LONG y = 0; y < r.bottom; y += 5)
            SendMessage(
                hNotificationArea,
                WM_MOUSEMOVE,
                0,
                (y << 16) + x);


    return 0;
}
```

If someone here is literate in C++ it would be great if you could look this over and see what dumb things I may have done. I am not offended by legitimate criticism.  Also - if someone thinks it's valuable to have this in C# I'm game for that.

Comment: You shouldn't have `DoEvents` something sent to `Task.Run`.  It will typically be in a worker thread that doesn't have a dispatcher or message loop.

Comment: There's no need to use the Win32 dlls. Winforms has a built in NotifyIcon component that can be used. This can then be disposed, which removes it from the tray.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.notifyicon?view=windowsdesktop-7.0 . Most of this code can be simplified by setting up the various properties and events in the designer.

Comment: @Craig Yes - you are right.  Those are not part of my final code.  I often put them there to host breakpoints.  Probably not a good practice either since I do forget to remove them sometimes...

Comment: @Julian Indeed, but this isn't the problem I am solving.  Applications don't always end elegantly so you don't have any opportunity to dispose of the notifyicon properly.  Killing an application in Taskmanager is an example that leaves a zombie icon in the system tray.  Also an unhandled error that terminates the program does the same thing.   Having something that can clean up the system tray is friendlier than leaving it littered is better IMHO.

Comment: As an alternative breakpoint target, you could use e.g. `Debug.Print` or `Debug.WriteLine`.  These are potentially preferable for having fewer visible effects on program execution.